# Error: Unable to find GraphQL endpoint. While trying to generate post type object

Tags: wordpress, graphql, apollo, headless, faust

Im trying to setup a headless WP project using faustjs, WPgraphQL and ACF. Later im planning to also implement Shopify shopfront API. I was setting up the project, installing all the plugins and setting them up. So i have setup my .env.local and i have setup the faust settings in the WP admin panel.

After adding some custom fields and adding content that i could fetch, i tried to generate a post types object using "npm run generate", but after running the command i get this error.

error - Unable to find a GraphQL endpoint at http://localhost:10039/index.php?graphql
error - WPGraphQL may not be active, or your WordPress site is unavailable.

I have looked this error up but i can't find a solution for it.

I tried different ways in starting such project as described above. First i tried to use the Atlas: Headless WP plugin and using a Shopify Blueprint. Everything went well until i tried to run "npm run dev". After that i got the same error.

I also tried a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9iEqOCvMpM&ab_channel=WPEngine). I used all the code supplied in the video, but when i tried opening the site that was running localy, i got an Apollo error: failed to fetch.

After troubleshooting for some time nothing worked, so i decided to try a different [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q71fEdtqoHI&ab_channel=WPEngineBuilders) (Current project) and that's where i ran into the problem with the "npm run generate" command.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue in my local dev environnement. Upon searching the project, I located the line of code generating the error message. I observed that this line is within a try/catch block, and there is an 'err' variable that could potentially provide more detailed information about why the error. To summarize, there were indeed additional details. In my specific situation, I was utilizing HTTPS with self-signed certificates, and 'node-fetch' was producing an error due to the certificates not being validated. I fixed it by adding NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 to the .env file.

Comment: @DayronGallardo Thanks. You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue in my local dev environment. Upon searching the project, I located the line of code generating the error message. I observed that this line is within a try/catch block, and there is an 'err' variable that could potentially provide more detailed information about why the error.

To summarize, there were indeed additional details. In my specific situation, I was utilizing HTTPS with self-signed certificates, and 'node-fetch' was producing an error due to the certificates not being validated. I fixed it by adding NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 to the .env file.